# How to get linked text from cell and set text in other cell with link attached using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to get the linked Text value from a cell and set it in another cell with the URL attached.

For example:
I have the following linked text value in cell A1. I want to get this URL-linked text and set it in another cell with the link attached. When I used getValue() method, the link with this value is lost. Is there any other way that we can do it using Google Apps Script? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using `getRichTextValue()` instead of `getValue()` as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const src = "A1"; // Source cell.
  const dst = "B1"; // Destination cell.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const richTextValue = sheet.getRange(src).getRichTextValue();
  sheet.getRange(dst).setRichTextValue(richTextValue);
}
```

- This sample script copies from "A1" to "B1" with the richTextValue.
- In this case, you can also use the following sample script.

  ```
    const src = "A1"; // Source cell.
    const dst = "B1"; // Destination cell.

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sheet.getRange(src).copyTo(sheet.getRange(dst));
  ```

#### References:

- [getRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue)
- [setRichTextValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue)

Comment: that solved the issue. Just one last thing, can I store it in an array rather than setting it up in the destination cell? Thank you

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `Just one last thing, can I store it in an array rather than setting it up in the destination cell?`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand it, how about `const ar = sheet.getRange("A1:C5").getRichTextValues()`? In this case, the cells "A1:C5" are retrieved and put to an array which is a 2-dimensional array. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getRichTextValue()` to get the link from text.

**Sample script will look like this:-**

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var range  = sheet.getRange('A1')
  var linkURL = range.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()
```

Reference:-

[getRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue)